# How does an image look like in a database, so I can check if my image is stored and displayed properly

Tags: android, sqlite

So I'm storing an image, name, desc, price of meals. So far only the image isn't showing up in the recycler view. And I think it has something to do with the image not storing properly, or not getting displayed correctly. If the pictures aren't clear, the Image column is showing '00' when there is an image stored. Though I'm not sure if this actually means there is an image stored.

[image: My SQLite database for storing meals]

[image: What my recycler view with the name, desc, price looks like]

**MenuDatabaseHelper.java**
This only contains Name, Desc and Price because I took this from a different tutorial which doesn't include images.

```
public boolean insertMenuData(String Menu_Name, String Menu_Desc, String Menu_Price){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(MENU_NAME, Menu_Name);
    contentValues.put(MENU_DESC, Menu_Desc);
    contentValues.put(MENU_PRICE, Menu_Price);

    long result = db.insert(MENU_TABLE, null, contentValues);

    return result != -1; //if result = -1 data doesn't insert
}
```

**MenuDatabaseHelper.java**
The storeImage and insertMenuData are separated.

```
public void storeImage(Menu menu){
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Bitmap imageToStoreBitmap = menu.getImage();

        objectByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageToStoreBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,objectByteArrayOutputStream);

        imageInBytes = objectByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("Image", imageInBytes);
        long checkIfQueryRuns = db.insert(MENU_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        if (checkIfQueryRuns!=-1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Data added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Data no added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**MenuDatabaseHelper.java**

```
public List<Menu> getMenuList(){
    try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String columns[] = {MENU_IMAGE, MENU_NAME, MENU_DESC, MENU_PRICE};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(MENU_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        byte[] index1 = cursor.getBlob(1);
        Bitmap mealImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(index1, 0, index1.length);

        int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(MENU_NAME);
        String mealName = cursor.getString(index2);
        int index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(MENU_DESC);
        String mealDesc = cursor.getString(index3);
        int index4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(MENU_PRICE);
        double mealPrice = cursor.getDouble(index4);

        Menu menu = new Menu(mealImage, mealName, mealDesc, mealPrice);
        menuList.add(menu);
    }
    return menuList;
}catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
}
}
```

**EDIT**

**MenuAdding.java**

*onClickListener for inserting name,desc,price*

```
add_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = add_name.getText().toString();
            String desc = add_desc.getText().toString();
            String price = add_price.getText().toString();
            //db.insertMenuData(name, desc, price);
            if (!name.equals("") && !desc.equals("") && !price.equals("") && db.insertMenuData(name, desc, price){
                Toast.makeText(MenuAdding.this, "Data added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                add_name.setText("");
                add_desc.setText("");
                add_price.setText("");
                listItem.clear();
                viewData();
            }   else {
                Toast.makeText(MenuAdding.this, "Data not added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

**MenuAdding.java**

*onClick I created just for storing images in database, it is sharing the same button as inserting name,desc,price(above onClickListener code).*

```
public void storeImage(View view){
    try {
        if (add_image.getDrawable() != null && imagetoStore != null) {
            db.storeImage(new Menu(imagetoStore));
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }}
```

I figured out that `DEFAULT X'00'` was causing the image in database to appear as '00', and it would make any NULL be defaulted to '00' so I could run the app without crashing. So basically, '00' is NULL.

**MenuDatabaseHelper.java**

```
private static final String CREATE_MENU_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MENU_TABLE +
        " ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        //MENU_IMAGE_NAME + " TEXT , " +
        MENU_IMAGE + " BLOB DEFAULT X'00', " +
        MENU_NAME + " TEXT , " +
        MENU_DESC + " TEXT , " +
        MENU_PRICE + " REAL ) " ;
```

Comment: When it comes to storing images, you should really consider storing the **path** to your image, rather than the full bitmap in a single column.

Comment: @ArthurAttout I think that wouldn't really work for my case, I need an admin to add these menu items. And need the user to be able to see it. Instead of just taking it from the internal storage and displaying.

Comment: I'm unsure what your problem is. This would be completely transparent to the user, the user would see the images just like any other image, it's just the way you store it that is updated. Even if the pictures are dynamic, you can download the image, save it in the internal storage and save that path in your database.

Comment: @ArthurAttout I can see how it would work now, however, I would try it if I wasn't running out of time. So for now, I'll stick to using the database method and find the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long while I finally found the problem! It was somehow due to having 2 similar methods that would insert the data into the database(1 method only inserted name, desc, price and another was for inserting image). Which caused the Button to only register the method `insertMenuData()` and completely ignore the method for `storeImage()`. Even though I checked somewhere else that a Button is able to handle 2 different onClickListener() at once(maybe I messed up there as well). In the end I had to combine my method `storeImage()` into `insertMenuData`, and it worked.

So in short, very bad idea to mix similar codes together from different tutorial without fully understanding it.

**MenuDatabaseHelper.java**

*Combined `storeImage()` method and `insertMenuData()` method*

```
public boolean insertMenuData(Menu menu, String Menu_Name, String Menu_Desc, String Menu_Price){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    Bitmap imageToStoreBitmap = menu.getImage();

    objectByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageToStoreBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,objectByteArrayOutputStream);

    imageInBytes = objectByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    contentValues.put(MENU_IMAGE, imageInBytes);
    contentValues.put(MENU_NAME, Menu_Name);
    contentValues.put(MENU_DESC, Menu_Desc);
    contentValues.put(MENU_PRICE, Menu_Price);

    long result = db.insert(MENU_TABLE, null, contentValues);

    return result != -1; //if result = -1 data doesn't insert
}
```

**MenuAdding.java**

*onClickListener for adding data button*

```
        add_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = add_name.getText().toString();
            String desc = add_desc.getText().toString();
            String price = add_price.getText().toString();
            //db.insertMenuData(name, desc, price);
            if (!name.equals("") && !desc.equals("") && !price.equals("") && db.insertMenuData(new Menu(imagetoStore), name, desc, price) 
                    && add_image.getDrawable() != null && imagetoStore != null){
                Toast.makeText(MenuAdding.this, "Data added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //db.storeImage(new Menu(imagetoStore));
                add_name.setText("");
                add_desc.setText("");
                add_price.setText("");
                listItem.clear();
                viewData();
            }   else {
                Toast.makeText(MenuAdding.this, "Data not added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Also to answer my own question of how would an image look like in a database. It would be a very long number.
[image]